# Sort hypen separated value in mysql varcharfield

Tags: mysql

How to sort a hyphen separated number in mysql varchar field. I have list of number in a field

```
700-657-1
700-657-10
700-657-2
700-657-3
700-657-4
```

Comment: You could get the relevant substrings, cast them to `INT` and sort as your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **always** have three-part (fixed count or you can determine what is the maximum count of parts) values, then you have two choices:

- Consider to rethink your schema to store the data in separate columns (the exact parts should have some meaning)
- Parse the string with string functions, then sort that parsed values

An example how to do the second option:

```
SELECT
  val,
  CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, '-', 1), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(VAL, '-', 0)) + 1), '-', '') AS UNSIGNED ) AS first,
  CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, '-', 2), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(VAL, '-', 1)) + 1), '-', '') AS UNSIGNED ) AS second,
  CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, '-', 3), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(VAL, '-', 2)) + 1), '-', '') AS UNSIGNED ) AS third
FROM
  test
ORDER BY
  first ASC, second ASC, third ASC
```

You can move the expression to the `ORDER BY` clause if you do not want to return them.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57a7a/5)

**EDIT**

```
SELECT
  val
FROM
  test
ORDER BY
  CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, '-', 1), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, '-', 0)) + 1), '-', '') AS UNSIGNED ) ASC,
  CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, '-', 2), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, '-', 1)) + 1), '-', '') AS UNSIGNED ) ASC,
  CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, '-', 3), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, '-', 2)) + 1), '-', '') AS UNSIGNED ) ASC
```

Comment: thanks for input. Is that possible to cast at the end of the mysql query . I mean is it possible to place the cast function after order by?

Comment: cool. it is working. But one more question . instead of appending asc with all the cast can be a single one?

Comment: @Anish you could omit all `ASC` because this is the default direction for ORDER BY.

Comment: It can be, if you know the maximum digits for all parts. You can add leading zeros (after parsing), than you can implode those zero-filled parts. (But I think it is a bit more work to do). The best option is to rethink either the table's structure or the stored values should be stored in a form which can be sorted properly.

Comment: Or if @VMai interpreted your last question correctly, yes, you can leave all ASC, but I like to add them to the ORDER BY definition.

Comment: yea I removed and append the order by condition at the end and it is working thanks @Pred and vmai

Comment: You can omit the last `ASC` too. Please note, that the `ASC/DESC` keyword applies only to the column immediately preceding it!